# ContextMenu on tap instead of tap and hold

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I need to open up a menu and since WP7 is `not designed` to perform such actions, I am taking help of Toolkit. Following is the sample code:

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" Padding="6">
     <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
         <toolkit:ContextMenu>
             <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" Click="Item1_Click" />
             <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2" Click="Item2_Click" />
             <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item3" Click="Item3_Click" />
         </toolkit:ContextMenu>
     </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
     <TextBlock Text="Tap" />
</Border>
```

Now this works fine as long as user does a press and hold action. But I can't ask the user for such action. I need to display the menu on a single click/tap/touch/gesture (watever you want to call it). Can someone please suggest? If you think toolkit is not the best way, then please suggest alternatives with sample code. I tried popup but that did more bad than good to my applicaiton

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add `GestureListener` to the `Border` and subscribe to the `Tap` event. In the event handler, you get the `ContextMenu` for the `Border` and set `IsOpen` to true if it doesn't have a logical parent.

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" Padding="6">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" Click="Item1_Click" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2" Click="Item2_Click" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item3" Click="Item3_Click" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <TextBlock Text="Tap" />
</Border>

private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = sender as Border;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(border);
    if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
    {
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does the job. On a side note. Any idea on how to highlight the selected option. I want to just highlight the selected row with row background color set to gray or something

Comment: @Ravi: Do you have to highlight the selected `MenuItem` based on some condition prior to opening the `ContextMenu`? Maybe try to name the `MenuItem` s and set `menuItem1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);` based on the condition

Comment: awesome ... thanks ... i didn't try it on the menuitem but used elsewhere and works like a charm.

Comment: hi, there seems to be a problem with this solution, when I first start my application and tap on the text box the context menu is at the top of the screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ekOOI.png  When I switch the page in my pivot navigation the context menu changes in position: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0Hb.png Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a context menu for your application, then the `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuService` are the best approach to take because it is standard throughout third party and pre-installed applications. Users already understand the 'tap-and-hold' gesture, so working around that will be counter-intuitive.

If (for whatever reason) you must initiate a `ContextMenu` from a single tap, then you can always customize the source code for [ContextMenu.cs](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61053#1325051) from the Silverlight Toolkit so that instead of hooking the `Hold` event it hooks the `Tap` event.

Comment: Hi Derek, that didn't help much. Considering the fact that I am pretty new to WP7 and silverlight, I checked the surce code but didn't understand much. Can you please help me in changing the tap and hold action to just tap?

Comment: Download the source code for Silverlight Toolkit, open the source file I referenced, change the `.Hold += ` to `.Tap +=`, recompile, update the reference in your projec to the new assembly. I still doubt very much changing default behavior is the right way to go, though.

Comment: Hi Derek, you are probably right. I should go with the suggestion of Meleak and use gesture service. Thanks anyways